# Proper way to present nested tree

Tags: ios, user-interface, user-experience

I have tree like this:

```
Root
-CountryA
    -RegionA
        -producerA
    -RegionB
        -ProducerB
        -ProducerC
    -RegionC
        -ProducerD
-CountryB
.
.
Several countries with the same pattern
```

And I have to reach one producer.

At first I've used a `UITableViewController` for each level but in time I saw that this is not the best approach. Now I'm thinking about one `UTableViewController` with expandable cells.

How you handle similar problem?

Comment: You should use a single TableViewController. If a user wants to 'expand' a row you just insert the cells. If you need a custom animation to insert the cells you should think about using CollectionViewController (and just organise the cells in the same way a tableview would) and create a custom insertion animation

Comment: I would actually use a UICollectionView. This will give you much greater flexibility and a far nicer UI. You could present a nicer graphical interface for each of your tree levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest inserting new cells under chosen one.

You have

```
-CountryA
-CountryB
-CountryC
```

User selects CountryB. Then, in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: use method insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: with index paths section 0 and rows 2-(number of regions in CountryB).

Comment: One more - you should store info on expanded/unexpanded cells. It will be required in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to understand how actually populate requested cell. 
For this intendant on left I use simply transparent background and non transparent subview under content with left edge on a proper distance from left edge of cell's content view